Does time reversal invariance imply that one-photon exchange amplitude should be real?
I am reading a paper where authors discuss a process of elastic electron-proton scattering. They briefly state that in the one-photon exchange process, the scattering amplitude is real due to time reversal invariance of electromagnetic interactions. In another paper written by some other people, the same claim is made. The difference is that they consider the scattering of an electron on a spin-0 nucleus.
I could potentially establish that the amplitude, M, is real in a brute force way. However, I want to understand how this conclusion is derived from time reversal invariance. I am a novice in QFT, so if someone could explain it in detail, I would appreciate it. Thank you.
